# Dynamic word change Svelte

Tags: svelte

Im trying to change a word using an array, but I get this error:

```
(plugin svelte) ValidationError: $ is an illegal variable name
```

This is my code:

```svelte
<script>
 var words = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "pizza"
];
var t = setInterval(function($) {
  var randomNumber = Math.round( Math.random() * (words.length-1) );
  $('#changing').fadeOut("normal", function(){
        $('#changing').html( words[ randomNumber ] + "." ).fadeIn("normal");
    })
}, 4500);
</script>

<span id="changing">word</span>
```

How I can fix this? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working solution [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/1ca7c07eef5f4efab3c21ac5aef79044?version=3.38.3).  (There are a few more words and shorter time span to speed the eval process, but you can revert those.)

Basically, you have to create a time interval and update a variable when each interval clicks over.  Then, in your HTML, you can just set the variable directly with curly braces, as demonstrated in the REPL.

Then, to get the fade event, we can use a `{#key <variable>}` block, which basically looks for the change in a value and then destroys/recreates the element.  It's pretty simple once you see it.

Then, I just have some css styling at the bottom to bring all of the elements inline.